# Is there a word for a job role created that gives no practical benefit?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to find if there is a word or term for a job role that has been created by a manager that gives no real practical benefit to the business, but was done to give the illusion of change.

Say for instance a manager of a failing factory wants to convince the owners he can still turn the business around. He makes a change by creating a new deputy foreman role and says this will increase productivity, but in reality he is just reallocating existing duties from other posts to buy time.

The closest word I could think of was stooge, but this doesn't sound right as it describes the person not the job. Any ideas?

Comment: A sinecure is a job that involves no or little real work, but this is an overlapping rather than identical concept.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, indeed, I'd say *sinecure* matches the question in the title perfectly, but not that of the fuller explanation, where the job does benefit the company, just not any more than the previous job of the same person did.

Comment: The expression that comes to mind here is 'rearranging the deck-chairs on the Titanic' – but that assumes the factory actually does fold.

Comment: More colloquial terms than sinecure are 'soft-option' or 'cushy-number'. Recently I was talking to someone whose grandfather lived in Holland during the Nazi occupation. Anyone who didn't have work was in danger of being deported to a labour camp in Germany. So many Dutch businesses gave people completely unnecessary tasks to fulfill, like rearranging copious lists of things into alphabetical order, or copying from  telephone directories etc, just so that it appeared they were working. Unfortunately I didn't ask if this practice had a name, but you have made me want to try and find out.

Comment: Two further options though one should be very careful because they are charged: make-work and union job. Both will greatly depend on the view of the people you are talking to, but both can most definitely refer to what the OP is asking.

Comment: In publishing (and probably elsewhere) this tactic is sometimes known as "CYA management," where _CYA_ stands (in U.S. English) for "cover your ass."

Answer (score 1):

Consider **org-chart shuffle**.  You can find several references to this phrase on the web, such as [this one](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/mark-gongloff/jamie-dimon-too-big-to-fail_b_1711736.html).

There is also the related concept of **[make-work](http://www.yourdictionary.com/make-work)**.

> (designating) a job, project, or assignment that serves no useful purpose other than to give an otherwise idle or unemployed person something to do